# c# MapHttpAttibuteRoutes cannot use same action with different parameter?

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am a newbie to c# and I am stuck at the attribute routes.

Now I want to create an API to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE user.

I dont know how to describe the problem and the most familiar I found is not correct answer to my case.

[How to use Route attribute to bind query string with web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199946/how-to-use-route-attribute-to-bind-query-string-with-web-api)

```
[HttpGet]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/users
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.ToList();
    }

    [Route("api/users/{FirstName?}/{LastName?}")]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetByFirstName(string FirstName = null, string LastName = null)
    { 
        var users = Enumerable.Empty<User>();
        if (FirstName != null && LastName != null)
            users = _context.Users.Where(u => (u.FirstName == FirstName) && (u.LastName == LastName));
        else if (FirstName != null)
            users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == FirstName);
        else if (LastName != null)
            users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.LastName == LastName);

        return users;
    }
}
```

This is what I have for my controller, and below is what I have for WebApiConfig.cs
Basically I used config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      // Web API configuration and services
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Why I cannot call api by 
http://localhost:50861/api/users?LastName=someName&FirstName=someName

Any advise is highly appreciate. Or any links to this problem is also helpful! Thanks

Edit: I just updated another part of my code. Since when I use the api above to query, I got the result of this /api/users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `GetByFirstName` like below

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/users/name")]
public IEnumerable<User> GetByFirstName(string FirstName = null, string LastName = null)
{ 
    var users = Enumerable.Empty<User>();
    if (FirstName != null && LastName != null)
        users = _context.Users.Where(u => (u.FirstName == FirstName) && (u.LastName == LastName));
    else if (FirstName != null)
        users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == FirstName);
    else if (LastName != null)
        users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.LastName == LastName);

    return users;
}
```

And then your url will be like

```
GET http://localhost:50822/api/users/name?FirstName=Will&LastName=abc
```

Comment: @William Shu, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: glad to hear that you have get rid from you problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You were defining route by

```
[Route("api/users/{FirstName?}/{LastName?}")]
```

So your call should like

```
http://localhost:50861/api/users/someName/someName
```

If you wants to calling api by querystring like your call then your route should be define like

```
[Route("api/users")]
```

But it will conflict with your GetUsers method. So you can define its like

```
[Route("api/users/byname")]
```

And call like

```
http://localhost:50861/api/users/byname?FirstName=abc&LastName=xyz
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It conflict my getUsers method. Actually, it doesnt work since it just return the value of getusers method. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Replace empty string by null and try

Comment: Thanks Abdul! It works this time. However, it only works when i pass in both parameters. I set the firstname and lastname to be null as arguments so they will be null if nothing pass in? Ex. if I say /api/users/byname?firstname=abc, the lastname parameter is null? I have updated the getbyfirstname method in case you need.

Comment: @William your route is the URL before the query string (the query string portion of the URL starts at `?`). It seems like you want to use query parameters, and not route parameters. A route like Abdul suggested (`/api/users/byname`) should achieve this.

Comment: @John Exactly, /api/users/byname helps me to use GetByFirstName method. However, if I say /api/users/byname/lastname=abc&firstname=def, it works. If I say /api/users/byname/lastname=abc, it returns nothong. I am wondering if my algorithm above is incorrect. If I write it as public IEnumerable<User> GetByName(string FirstName = null, string LastName = null), the variable lastname i get is a null? or a emptyspace?